# It's possible to convert XML documents to XRFF documents?

Tags: java, xml, weka, text-mining, arff

I am working in a Text Mining program with XML documents, but I don't know how to import the XML documents to Weka. How could I do it?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: please provide some code you have tried so far

Comment: I haven't tried any code, so I am looking for how to convert the XML file to an XRFF file.

Comment: read the xml with java and save it as arff?